# Solr error when attempting to use a field set to a fieldtype of solr.StrField

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I'm trying to setup faceting through Solr. I have a specific field to use called "Category". The faceting works, but appears lowercase and only contains a single word. I'm sure this is due to the field analyzer so I've change the field's type to "string". This produces a error! See below.

FYI - I'm using Solr 4.3.

You can see the fieldtype and the field below. You can see the field is set to the fieldtype "string". This field type uses "Solr.StrField". Why would using this fieldtype cause the error below?

### Schema.xml

```
<types> 
   <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" /> 
</types>

<fields> 
   <field name="category" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" 
   required="false" multiValued="false"/>    
</fields>
```

I'm getting the error message in the log and when attempting to run a query

> This AttributeSource does not have the attribute
>   'org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionIncrementAttribute'
>
> null:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This AttributeSource does not
>   have the attribute
>   'org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionIncrementAttribute'.

Update:
Since the error seems to indicate that my fieldtype should have the attribute PositionIncrementAttribute, I added to my string to test. I then cleared and re-indexed, but still no luck.

```
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" 
positionIncrementGap="100"/>
```

Comment: Did u re-index data after changing the fieldType?

Comment: Yes Jay, I re-indexed the data after changing the field type. After doing so I noticed the error when performing a query through the Solr Admin UI. The query failed and produced the error inside the query results, and the text was black. The error also displayed in the logging. Hope this helps. Please let me know if you have any other questions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you clear the index before reindexing? (and not just resubmitted your documents)? What does your schema look like now? (where do you have positionIncrement set?)

Comment: Yes, I cleared the index before reindexing. I noticed my fieldtypes that use class=solr.TextField have the attribute positionIncrementGap=100. This does not exist on my string field as you can see in my post.

Comment: FYI - I'm using the Data Import Handler to pull in data from SQL. I am not using SolrJ.